# Youtube Api ConnectionResult Error Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I've been trying to create a list of youtube videos in my android app. I made it work the way I wanted to. However it's only working in the debug mode. when I try to run the app I get the error:

```
Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
```

Maybe it's happening because there might be a restriction on the videos? In any case I think that the reason for the error is because Youtube Api is not giving me access to its Api. What do I need to do to get the access? So far I've only created API key and I've been using it in my app.

Comment: Can you post your codes of how you have added the API in your project.